# Filtering out parts of file path after a certain point

Tags: splunk

File paths are searching into a deeper level than intended. All i need is the /aaa but my search is populating all the values for /aaa/bbbb/ccc/ddd/. is there a way to remove everything after /aaa/?

```
my search: index=web_pn_iis sourcetype=iis  cs_uri_stem="*" sc_status=4* | where not cs_uri_stem="/*" 

returned values:/aaa/bbbb/ccc/ddd/
want: /aaa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rex` command can do that.

```
index=web_pn_iis sourcetype=iis  cs_uri_stem="*" sc_status=4* 
| where not cs_uri_stem="/*" 
| rex field=cs_uri_stem "(?<want>\/\w+)"
```